# How and where to define class variable when using header files in C++

Tags: c++, header, class-variables

```
/*
 * CDummy.h
 */
#ifndef CDUMMY_H_
#define CDUMMY_H_

class CDummy {

public:
    CDummy();
    virtual ~CDummy();
};

#endif /* CDUMMY_H_ */
```

I've read that one should not declare class variables in header files. ist this right?
So I declare it in the cpp file below:

```
/*
 * CDummy.cpp
*/

#include "CDummy.h"

static int counter = 0; //so here is my static counter. is this now private or public? how can i make it public, i cannot introduce a public block here.

CDummy::CDummy() {
  counter++;

}

CDummy::~CDummy() {
    counter--;
}
```

using this code i cannot access the classvariable from my main program....

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "class variable" needs to belong to a class. So it has to be *declared* in the class definition. If the class definition is in a header file, then it follows that the class variable *declaration* must also be in a header file.

The class variable's *definition* should go in an implementation file, typically the one in which the class' members are defined. Here's a simplified example:

Foo.h

```
struct Foo
{
  void foo() const;
  static int FOO;   // declaration
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
void Foo::foo() {}
int Foo::FOO = 42; // definition
```

What you have here:

```
static int counter = 0;
```

is a static variable that is *not* a static member of any class. It is only non-member static variable, static to the compilation unit of `CDummy.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

> static int counter = 0; //so here is my static counter. is this now private or public? how can i make it public, i cannot introduce a public block here.

From the code I see `counter` is just a global static variables as it is not declated anywhere in your `CDummy`

Static variables should be public so that you could initialize them outside the class declaration. Your code should look like this to have it public:

```
class CDummy {
public:
   static int count;
   CDummy();
   virtual ~CDummy();
};
// inside CDummy.cpp
int CDummy::count = 0;
```

[Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm) you can read more about how to use static variables in class declaration.